c++ filesystem error: recursive_directory_iterator::operator++: unknown error
I am a beginner in programming in general. I want to search for a folder/file with a specific name using the filesystem library's recursive_directory_iterator class but I keep getting this error message:

recursive_directory_iterator::operator++: unknown error

after running for a little while.
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

void search() {
    string filename;
    cin >> filename;
    fs::path path = "."; //i want the search to start in "users/name/"

    try {
        for (const auto& entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path, fs::directory_options::skip_permission_denied)) {
            cout << entry << endl;
            
            if (entry.path().filename() == filename) {
                cout << "File found: " << entry.path() << endl;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (fs::filesystem_error& e) {
        cout << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    search();

    return 0;
}

I was expecting the program to loop through every folder/file and display the ones which match the name of the file the user wants.
How do I need to fix my program to find files/folders?

Works for me on Ubuntu.

What compiler do you use? if MSVC, check this: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/3254

What compiler and standard library?  What versions of the compiler and standard library?    The <filesystem> header, and facilities in it such as recursive_directory_iterator were introduced into C++17.    Older compilers/libraries (say, before 2018, since it takes time for compilers/libraries to catch up and comply with the standard once it is ratified) will not support it.   And, in more recent compilers/libraries, the support is not necessarily complete. By default, compilation also often targets an older standard (the compiler support of older standards will be more mature/complete)

Am using gcc 6.3.0 as a compiler by the way

update I removed the .gradle folder and it works just fine does anyone have an explanation for this??
